# Filtering out neighboring ascending digits in quaternary numeral system

Tags: java, performance, number-systems

> Take in a natural number n ∈ N, then process and output a(n), with a(n) being the number of quaternary strings (with 0, 1, 2, 3) of length n, where (from left to right) there never follows a character (i + 1) directly after the character i.
>
> For example, n=3 results in a(3) = 42: 000, 002, 003, 020, 021, 022, 030, 031, 032,
>   033, 100, 102, 103, 110, 111, 113, 130, 131, 132, 133, 200, 202, 203,
>   210, 211, 213, 220, 221, 222, 300, 302, 303, 310, 311, 313, 320, 321,
>   322, 330, 331, 332, 333.

How can performance be improved? n = 13 already takes 4 seconds.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quaternary {

    public static void start(){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
        System.out.print("Enter number n: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        for (int k=0; k < 4; k++){
        findString(n, k, "", stringList);
        }

        System.out.println(“Number of strings with n = " + n +  " : "+ stringList.size());

        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        double time = (double)estimatedTime / 1000000000.0;
        System.out.println(time);
    }

    public static void findString(int n, Integer lastNumber, String string, List<String> stringList)
    {
        string += lastNumber.toString();

        if (string.length() == n)
        {
            stringList.add(string);
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (i != lastNumber+1)
                {
                    findString(n, i, string, stringList);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you timed your code in some way to figure out which part of the code is consuming the most time?

Comment: No I haven't. So placing time outputs at specific lines is the way to go?

Comment: That's what I would do.

Comment: Why is there no 001?

Comment: "Take in a natural number n ∈ N, then process and output a(n), with a(n) being the number of quaternary strings (with 0, 1, 2, 3) of length n, where (from left to right) there never follows a character (i + 1) directly after the character i."

Comment: The string handling and concatenation is quite expensive. It seems to me the solution could be rewritten using integers and arithmetic only. That should speed it up considerably.

Comment: Is using recursion a requirement?  I have a non-recursive solution that I have to take to n=1000 before I start to even notice delays in finishing.

Comment: No it's not a requirement. Could you please explain this solution?

Comment: Sounds promising! Would you please share your solution?

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing with a runtime upperbounded by something like 4^n here.

If you are building a list of strings anyway, why not reuse the list of valid strings in the list and append these values to a digit to get a new value?

```
public static void calculateQuarternary(int n) {

    int startPtr, endPtr;
    startPtr = endPtr = 0;

    ArrayList<String> alTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> alCurrent = new ArrayList<String>();

    alCurrent.add("0");
    alCurrent.add("1");
    alCurrent.add("2");
    alCurrent.add("3");


    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {

        endPtr = alCurrent.size();
        alTemp.clear();

        for (int j = 0; j < endPtr; ++j) {

            for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
                if (shouldAdd(alCurrent.get(j), k)) {
                    alTemp.add(k + alCurrent.get(j) + "");
                }
            }
        }

        alCurrent = new ArrayList<String>(alTemp);
    }
    System.out.println(alCurrent.size());
}

public static boolean shouldAdd(String s, int k) {

    int firstChar = (int)(s.charAt(0) - 48);
    return k + 1 != firstChar;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow,

Comment: One second- I will post some code soon.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that can be solved by small optimizations to your current algorithm.  Your problem is you are iterating through every valid combination, which is O(4<sup>n</sup>), where your requirements only call for you to *count* the valid combinations.  This requires sometimes tricky analysis to find patterns you can exploit, but can usually be done in O(n log n) or better.

I approach these sorts of problems by drawing a tree, where the first four branches from the root are numbers where the first digit is 0, 1, 2, and 3 respectively, the next layer of branches down is the second digit, and so forth.  With the restrictions you gave, an `n=2` tree looks like this:

[image: n=2 tree]

Now the trick is for any value of `n`, you want to count how many leaves are on the tree without actually building the entire tree.  Here, I take note that the count of each digit on the layer below is dependent on the count of other digits of the previous layer.  For example, each `0` on one layer will produce one `0`, one `2`, and one `3` on the layer below.  We don't much care what order those go in.  We just want to count them.  That can be done in O(n), as below:

```
depth = num_zeros = num_ones = num_twos = num_threes = 1

while depth < n: 
  num_zeros  = num_zeros + num_ones + num_twos + num_threes
  num_ones   =             num_ones + num_twos + num_threes
  num_twos   = num_zeros +            num_twos + num_threes
  num_threes = num_zeros + num_ones +          + num_threes
  depth = depth + 1

return num_zeros + num_ones + num_twos + num_threes
```

Answer (score 1):

I dropped all thoughts of recursion and exploited some java tricks I happen to know to resolve [padding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150760/1493294) and [string building](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/1493294).

The big ideas were to NOT slurp all this up in memory but dump it out as soon as I could as well as transforming the  "(i + 1) never follows i" rule into three simple tests.

Admittedly this hard codes the base but I think this approach is possible to generalize.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Quaternary quaternary = new Quaternary(3);
    quaternary.generate();
}

class Quaternary{
    int base = 4;
    String zeroes;

    Quaternary(int length) {
        //String of zeros as long as length
        zeroes = new String(new char[length]).replace("\0", "0");
    }

    void generate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)Math.pow(base, zeroes.length()); i++) {
            String s = Integer.toString(i, base);

            // pad with leading zeros if needed
            String result = s.length() < zeroes.length() 
                          ? zeroes.substring(s.length()) + s : s;

            if (!( result.contains("01")
                || result.contains("12")
                || result.contains("23")
            )) {
                System.out.print(", " + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I called n length.

n=3 outputs

```
, 000, 002, 003, 020, 021, 022, 030, 031, 032, 033, 100, 102, 103, 110, 111, 113, 130, 131, 132, 133, 200, 202, 203, 210, 211, 213, 220, 221, 222, 300, 302, 303, 310, 311, 313, 320, 321, 322, 330, 331, 332, 333
```